# use of printer using php

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter, printers

I have developed a POS application using codeigniter, I want to print a bill using printer, can any one help me to pass the printer name to php/javascript code to be get printed in, any help will be appreciated

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7242535/how-to-print-on-client-printer-from-server-using-php ?

Comment: everyone is correct that you can't automatically print things through a users browser, you can only open up the print context menu and they need to hit print.  But if you have a central printer for a bunch of registers you can setup a php print server that automatically prints.  Search `php print server`, there are some open source solutions that might work for you

Answer (score -2):

You cannot do that directly but u can use

```
window.print()
```

and hide the elements u dnt want to get printed by ur css

```
@media print
{    
  .no-print, .no-print *
  {
    display: none !important;
  }
}
```